# Jquery searchbox with icons or Images

Tags: jquery

Is it possible find free jquery searchbox plugin that shows the icon or image next to the text? If not, I will be happy for  jquery combobox like that [combobox](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxcombobox/jquery-combobox-getting-started.htm), but again with icons or images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :[WebKit HTML5 Search Inputs](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/)

Comment: Thank you, but I thinked next to every result in the search box. Do you undesrtand what I mean? :)

Comment: not sure whether this is what you want, but you check out the bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#forms look for 'Prepended and appended inputs'

Comment: I have in mind icon or image next to result of searchbox.
For example I write to searhbox Monkey and result will be 
[Image of monkey] Monkey.

Comment: Like this : [link](http://jamesskidmore.com/scripts/smartsuggest/)

Comment: get it now :). what are you using for autocomplete

Comment: http://codeblogging.net/blogs/1/15/

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. :) I am already using this plugin, but I didn´t know how put in to searchbox images. And Is it open source?

Comment: I badly explained my problem, so I´m sorry. :)

Comment: here the link which solve this problem with jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279041/implement-jquery-autocomplete-with-multiple-values-and-images-solved